# Arabic text in matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, arabic-support

xlabel and ylabel don't display Arabic

```
x = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
y = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

plt.bar(x, y, label='Bar1', color='red')
plt.xlabel("الفواصل")
plt.ylabel("الترتيبات")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: You won't see Arabic if the font doesn't have the Arabic glyphs. But what happens if you encode the Unicode text to UTF-8 bytes? Eg `"الفواصل".encode()`

Comment: Which Python version do you use? Upgrade to Python 3 if you are still using Python 2.7. Unicode / UTF-8 handling is somewhat broken in Python 2.7.

Comment: "الفواصل".encode() dosen't work

Comment: I use Python3, "الفواصل".encode("ascii", "ignore") dosen't work

Comment: @kay this has nothing to do with python 2 or 3.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, well ... see you own answer to confirm that it does. :P

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest All Unicode-related questions should mention the Python version (preferably via an appropriate tag) because Unicode handling is so different in Python 2 vs Python 3.

Comment: @kay what I mean is that a solution to a unicode problem cannot be to use a different python version.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, sure it can?! Many libraries don't play nice neither with UTF-8 strs nor with unicode. Many of these libraries work well in Python 3, though.

Answer (score 11):

You will first need to install both [arabic-reshaper](https://pypi.org/project/arabic-reshaper/) and [python-bidi](https://pypi.org/project/python-bidi/).

```
import arabic_reshaper
from bidi.algorithm import get_display
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
y = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
xlbl = get_display( arabic_reshaper.reshape('الفواصل'.decode('utf8')))
ylbl = get_display( arabic_reshaper.reshape('الترتيبات'.decode('utf8')))
plt.bar(x, y, label='Bar1', color='red')
plt.xlabel(xlbl, fontdict=None, labelpad=None)
plt.ylabel(ylbl, fontdict=None, labelpad=None)
plt.show()
```

plot Arabic

[image]

Comment: But the numbers are not Arabic

Answer (score -6):

It should work if you use unicode strings (`u"الفواصل"`) instead of usual strings.

```
x = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
y = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

plt.bar(x, y, label='Bar1', color='red')
plt.xlabel(u"الفواصل")
plt.ylabel(u"الترتيبات")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Or, in order to get the correct order

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
y = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

plt.bar(x, y, label='Bar1', color='red')
plt.xlabel(u"الفواصل"[::-1])
plt.ylabel(u"الترتيبات"[::-1])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I still have the same problem

Comment: In that case, you might need to update matplotlib. It might be that your version is too old and uses a font that does not have all unicode symbols available.

Comment: Yes, it should work, if the font actually has those Arabic glyphs. And the `u` prefix is only required in Python 2, in Python 3 all normal text strings are Unicode objects, so the `u` prefix isn't required (although recent Python 3 versions permit it for reasons of Python 2 compatibility).

Comment: BTW, there's still a big problem with this: the letters are in the wrong order (left-to-right) and disjoint.

Comment: I don't know how to connect the letters. But you may reverse the string for correct ordering.